# Substituting leading '+1' in Python with re module

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm sure this is definitely a simple and stupid question, but I can't figure out how to remove leading "+1" from a string using `re` module's `sub()`. I've been trying these

```
import re

re.sub("/+1","","+1585123456")
re.sub(r"^/+1","","+1585123456")
```

but they all return the same original string. Could someone help me point out the obvious mistake I'm making? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\` for escaping `+`, not `/`

```
re.sub(r"\+1","","+1585123456")
```

Answer (score 4):

You dont need regex to do this, if you always just want to remove the first two letters you can just do this

```
number = "+1585123456"
number = number[2:] 
'585123456'
```